# How to shuffle a vector of SFML rectangles?

Tags: c++, sfml

My project consists of 2 files:
SFMLSetup.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <ctime>
#include "SFMLHelpers.h"

int main()
{
    //Initialize window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Algorithm Visualizer", sf::Style::Default);


    //Create the line (rectangle) vector
    std::vector <sf::RectangleShape> lineVector;
    
    //Defines the number of obj's to be sorted 
    int N;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of items to be sorted: ";
    std::cin >> N;

    //Populates and shuffles line vector in preparation for sorting
    int xpos = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sf::RectangleShape line = plot(i + 1, xpos + i * 5, 200);  
        lineVector.push_back(line);
    }



    std::shuffle(std::begin(lineVector), std::end(lineVector), std::default_random_engine());

    //Event loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        //Event polling
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                    window.close();
                break;
            }
        }
                
        //Render
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        for (auto& itr : lineVector) {
            window.draw(itr);
        }
        

        
        //Draw your display
        window.display(); //Tell app that window is done drawing
    }

    //End of event loop

    std::cout << "Size of lineVector: " << lineVector.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto itr : lineVector) {
        sf::Vector2f size = itr.getSize();
        std::cout << "Heights of rectangles: " << size.x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and SFMLHelpers.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>



sf::RectangleShape plot(int len, int x, int y) { //Returns a single drawn line
    sf::RectangleShape line(sf::Vector2f(len, 1));
    line.setPosition(x, y - len);
    line.rotate(90);
    
    return line;
}
```

I have a vector of drawn lines that I eventually want to sort. My goal right now is to take the vector (which is initially sorted by size from 1 to N) and shuffle it with `std::shuffle`. The heights of the lines are being properly mixed up but the lines are maintaining their original order when it comes time to draw them.
[image: Console output]
[image: Drawing]

Initially, I tried using `std::random_device rd` in conjunction with `std::uniform_int_distribution <int> dist (1, N)`, and replacing  `i + 1` on line 34 of SFMLSetup.cpp with `dist(rd)`, but ran into the issue of lines being drawn multiple times. I'm not sure if that approach (creating and drawing the line vector in a random order) would be more appropriate than creating and then shuffling for my situation, and am open to either implementation.

Comment: The `rectangleShape` has all of the position information stored inside it. No matter what order you draw them in you're still going to get the same output. You'd need to shuffle the `x` positions. What you could do is shuffle the lines then override the x before drawing.

Comment: Alternatively, construct all your shapes with `x=0` and use the two-argument form of `RenderWindow::draw` to pass a custom transformation that shifts the object by the proper amount. Alternatively alternatively, construct the shapes ad hoc when drawing and just work with a list of heights.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I understand what you're saying, but I'm having a hard time with the implementation. Could you be a little more specific? Would I do that in the loop where I'm populating the vector or right before each call to draw?

Comment: You would need to override the horizontal position right before you draw each one.